# HttpModule over multiple sites

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have custom redirection implemented in a module. Do I have to modify each config for all sites or is there a more general approach?Also, I have files in App_Data for this module, which would cause replication.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (I am assuming you know. how to create a dll project, registering an Assembly in GAC, and modify the machine.config)

put your redirection-code in seperate dll project.
Register the assembly in the GAC.
Reference that assembly in all the projects/ applications where you need.

Open the machine.config and put the configs in machine.config in httpmodule section.just like you did in web.config.

Now it applies on all the applications(dotnet) where you would need.

Comment: So it involves modifying machine.config. I was thinking about that direction. Thank you very much. Although I've not tested yet, I'll mark this answer as replying my question

Comment: One question. Do I have to add reference to the assembly or modify web.configs and add httpmodule reference to the registered assembly in each needed project?

Comment: all application level configurations are derived from machine.config. If you have defined a section already in machine.config you don't need to repeat it again in web.config/ app.config. Until you decide to override the properties.